# Cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have base abastract class Employee with pure virtual method clone

```
virtual Employee* clone() const = 0;
```

Also i have derived class DeveloperEmployee that override this method:

```
DeveloperEmployee* clone() const override {
        return new DeveloperEmployee(this->description, this->project);
}
```

Now I have these lines in main:

```
DeveloperEmployee* a = new DeveloperEmployee(description, project);
DeveloperEmployee* a_copy = a->clone();
```

And I cannot change these lines. It says me that I can't instantiate abstract class, so how should I change the code?

If I change overrided method to

```
Employee* clone() const override {
        return new DeveloperEmployee(this->description, this->project);
}
```

I have cast problem in main and I cannot change main.

Comment: You've changed the returned type, which means no proper override. An regardless of that, the idea about Polymorphism is actually to use the same (base-class) type.

Comment: @OznOg 
It's allowed: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual#Covariant_return_types

Comment: @goodvibration ^

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: Also please add the exact wording of the error message.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the other answers mean by "you don't override, because return type is different". Return type is not part of the function signature, and it is perfectly fine to change return type to a derived one, **provided that** return type was originally a pointer or reference to a type (i.e. they are [covariant types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual#Covariant_return_types) - thanks for the link HolyBlackCat).

The following example compiles (with warning about unused variable). [See it online!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LZmusAo2GAGIBAVa):

```
class A{
public:
    virtual A* foo() const = 0;
};

class B:public A{
public:
    B* foo() const override {return new B();}
};

int main() {
    B b;
    A* ptr = b.foo();
}
```

If it wasn't allowed, compiler would throw an error thanks to the `override` keyword, for example in GCC:

```
prog.cc:12:17: error: conflicting return type specified for 'virtual 

std::__cxx11::string B::bar()'
     std::string bar() override { return {}; }
                 ^~~
prog.cc:6:20: note: overridden function is 'virtual double A::bar()'
     virtual double bar() = 0;
                    ^~~
```

---

The problem is somewhere in the code you don't show. Perhaps you're trying to create a variable of type `Employee` somewhere?

Comment: No it says that problem is in this line of code, so I don't really understand what's the problem, I can provide you a whole code if you want

Comment: @YuriyRusanov "I can provide you a whole code if you want" no you want to provide us enough information so we can help you, not the other way around

Comment: @Yuriy As asked by HolyBlackCat in the comments, you should provide the full error message (it usually indicates the line and file where error was made)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I thought that it would emit a conflicting return type error as in the usual case. This is something new to me. Thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score -4):

`DeveloperEmployee* clone() const override` can not override `virtual Employee* clone() const` since the return types are different. As long as you don't override `virtual Employee* clone() const` you can not instantiate an instance of `DeveloperEmployee` since it's a pure virtual function.

`DeveloperEmployee` should have the following definition.

```
Employee* clone() const override {
        return new DeveloperEmployee(this->description, this->project);
}
```

It's hard to understand what you mean by that you can't change the main, but to exploit polymorphism you would ideally create a base class pointer, assign it with the address of a derived class object and pass the pointer around.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual#Covariant_return_types

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the reference.This is something new to me.  I thought that it would emit a conflicting return type error as in the usual case.